# Can't remove PPA

Tags: ppa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

I installed the PPA for a detailed battery applet which won't install nor update. So I decided to remove the PPA and I installed PPA Purge and when I put in `sudo ppa-purge ppa:iaz/battery-status`, I get this:

Updating packages lists
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/fredp/ppa/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/fredp/ppa/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/fredp/ppa/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/iaz/battery-status/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/iaz/battery-status/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/iaz/battery-status/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason
PPA to be removed: iaz battery-status
Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: iaz battery-status

How do I  fix this?